# How to render the current page in views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

So the issue is quite simple.  The end user fills out a form and hits submit,  I want the page to then reload (if successful).  The issue is that the form is located on each users profile page, not a static url.  So I'm unable to do:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/{{ username }}')
```

I know I cannot pass a variable in this example, but I'm not sure how else to do this.  Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?  Is there way to just refresh the current page?  I'm not looking for any ajax solutions right now, I'm simply just trying to reload the current page when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not reload the same page if its a POST request, you should always redirect (see [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).  So I assume you mean you would like to redirect to the same view upon successful submission.

You can get the currently logged in user with `request.user`, so you might want to try something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def some_view(request):
  form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
     # do something
     return redirect('/accounts/{}'.format(request.user))
  return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

However, it would be better if you have named your accounts url pattern:

```
url('/accounts/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'some.view', name='user-home')
```

Now, you can do this:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # do something
        return redirect('user-home', username=request.user)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```